# Unable to remove first character from a string in Python 3

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup

I'm using Beautiful Soup to crawl the data from a website.

```
# Get the price
# productPrice = "¥249.00"
productPrice = soup.find('span', class_='price').text # this line returns a string ¥249.00 
currPrice = productPrice.lstrip("¥") # remove currency sign
print(currPrice) 
print(type(currPrice))
```

The above code is not removing the first character, the output is:

> ¥249.00
> <class 'str'>

However, if I switch to use local variable and try to remove the first character, it works fine

```
# Get the price
productPrice = "¥249.00"
# productPrice = soup.find('span', class_='price').text # this line returns a string ¥249.00 
currPrice = productPrice.lstrip("¥") # remove currency sign
print(currPrice) 
print(type(currPrice))
```

The above code output is:

> 249.00
> <class 'str'>

I tried using slicing like: `currPrice = productPrice[1:]` but was still not able to remove the first character. What can be the issue here?

Comment: What do `print(repr(currPrice))` and `print(list(map(ord, currPrice)))` show?

Comment: Are you sure `¥` *is* the first character of the string returned by `soup.find`?

Comment: @KellyBundy `print(repr(currPrice))` returns: `'\n¥249.00 '`

Comment: @chepner yes, it is guaranteed that first character is always `¥`

Comment: @casper You just showed that it's **not** the first character.

Comment: yeah, I also just noticed that. It's weird why I get that `\n` first.  Thanx for the guide @KellyBundy

Comment: If you want to extact an amount from that string, I suggest you to use a regex. That's more reliable.

Comment: You seem to have found the answer for your particular case - but for future reference, another possible explanation for character matching problems like this is that Unicode sometimes has multiple ways of representing a character, that do NOT test as equal.  Specifically, `\u00A5` and `\uFFE5` are both variants of the yen symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case the pattern is still the same and you only like to get the `float` like value you can `split()` by currency sign and `strip()` the last element in `ResultSet`:

```
productPrice='\n¥249.00 '
currPrice = productPrice.split('¥')[-1].strip()

#output
#249.00
```

**Note:** *Output is still a `string` until you converted it to a real `float` -> `currPrice = float(currPrice)`*